# Laravel - Populating dropdown with two columns as display type

Tags: laravel-5, collections

I am using the pluck api to get two columns and make a collection be passed in the view to make a dropdown menu.

```
Province::pluck('name', 'id');
```

It works fine and Province 'name' is displayed and id is used value. But I want to display two columns i.e name and total_population.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Eloquent's `pluck()` method won't let you do that, but you could approach this through other collection methods after executing a normal query. There are at least 2 ways to accomplish this:

With [`mapWithKeys()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-mapwithkeys) only

```
$provinces = Province::all(['id', 'name', 'total_population'])
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($province) {
        return [$province->id => "{$province->name} ({$province->total_population})"];
    });
```

With [`keyBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keyby) + [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map)

```
$provinces = Province::all(['id', 'name', 'total_population'])
    ->keyBy('id')
    ->map(function ($province) {
        return "{$province->name} ({$province->total_population})";
    });
```

I personally prefer the latter, but you are free to pick either one. :)